# Cannot access a disposed object UserManagerProxy

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

After upgrading to .NET 5 and using the latest version of the ASP.NET Boilerplate (not ABP Framework / ABP.io), the following line creates a error in my console -- 'Cannot access a disposed object UserManagerProxy'. When I try to step into the method to debug, Visual Studio simply executes the method and my console window displays the error message listed in the title.

Update: Added teh complete code

```
var user = new User
            {
                TenantId = tenant.Id,
                Name = name,
                Surname = surname,
                EmailAddress = emailAddress,
                IsActive = true,
                UserName = userName,
                IsEmailConfirmed = isEmailConfirmed,
                Roles = new List<UserRole>()
            };
            user.SetNormalizedNames();

            foreach (var defaultRole in await _roleManager.Roles.Where(r => r.IsDefault).ToListAsync())
            {
                user.Roles.Add(new UserRole(tenant.Id, user.Id, defaultRole.Id));
            }
          
            user.IsEmailConfirmed = isEmailConfirmed;
            user.ShouldChangePasswordOnNextLogin = true
            await _userManager.InitializeOptionsAsync(AbpSession.TenantId);
            CheckErrors(await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, plainPassword));
        CurrentUnitOfWork.SaveChanges();
```

Anyone experienced the same issue and if so, how was it solved?

Comment: Show the function signature and any attributes.

Comment: Also show the stack trace.

Comment: did you try making your method virtual and adding a unitofworkl attribute?

Comment: Aaron and Muhammad, after thinking through what you guys said, I have managed to figure out a working solution. I will add my code and preamble to the solution and close out this issue. Thanks for giving me the idea on where to look - cheers , Ivan

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around. While I am not sure what was creating the parent transaction to be disbanded, what I believe to be happening is that he prior call before entering into the 'RegisterByDefault' method, terminates the transaction. I believe the [UnitOfWork(transaction)] attribute with a required value would be equivalent to what my solution turned out to be.. I may refactor the below at some stage but the issue killed my sprint time and I need to get back to feature work...
**Here is what I have working for now**

```
 private async Task<User> RegisterByDefaultAsync(parms)
    {
        tenant = await GetActiveTenantAsync(tenantId:tenantId.Value);

        using (var uow = _uowMgr.Begin(System.Transactions.TransactionScopeOption.Required))
        {
            var user = new User
            {
                TenantId = tenant.Id,
                Name = name,
                Surname = surname,
                EmailAddress = emailAddress,
                IsActive = true,
                UserName = userName,
                IsEmailConfirmed = isEmailConfirmed,
                Roles = new List<UserRole>()
            };
            user.SetNormalizedNames();
            user.IsEmailConfirmed = isEmailConfirmed;
            user.ShouldChangePasswordOnNextLogin = false;
            uow .Complete();
            return user;
        }
    }
```